# Global Error Handler in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[image: I want to capture this err. And need to extract component name in that URL. How can I capture zone.js error?? and trace it into the component?]

Here's I have attached my code. I have implemented global handler and now I need to extract 'dashboard' from **500 Error** on zone.js. How can I get it in the global Handler. Is there any way that I can get my desired output?

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { LogService } from './logging-service.service';
import * as StackTrace from 'stacktrace-js';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private errors = new Array<any>();
  constructor(public injector: Injector, public zone: NgZone) {
  }
  public handleError(error: any) {
    console.log('Im a global handler', JSON.parse(error));
    const logService = this.injector.get(LogService);
    const location = this.injector.get(LocationStrategy);
    const message = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    const url = location instanceof PathLocationStrategy
      ? location.path() : '';
    const callbackFun = function (stackframes) {
      const stringifiedStack = stackframes.map(function (sf) {
        return sf.toString();
      }).join('\n');
      console.log(stringifiedStack);
    };


    const errback = function (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(err.stack);
    };
    window.onerror = function (msg, file, line, col, error) {
      // this.zone.fromError.subscribe(this.onZoneError);
      StackTrace.fromError(message).then(callbackFun).catch(errback);
      StackTrace.get().then(callbackFun).catch(message);
    };
    const handleErrorData = {
      // Some Json to send to server
    };
    logService.logError(handleErrorData);
    throw error;
  }
  public onZoneError(error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.error('Error', error instanceof Error ? error.message : error.toString());
  }

}
```

Comment: You can get that from your path that is if the injected subclass for `LocationStrategy` is `PathLocationStrategy`. `const parentPath = url.split('/')[1]`

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule In that I'm getting browser path. i.e. browser url not the service URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) (requires Angular 4.3.x)

From there listen to errors and extract the request url and split it into its parts.

Comment: can you add your code, for me it still throwing errors from zone.js

Comment: Hey, you might want to check out the docs. https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses